# How to click and "unclick" an element

Tags: jquery

Okay, I'm a real beginner when it comes to jQuery, and although I've tried searching for this already, I can't seem to find an answer (I'm probably not phrasing it correctly).

When one of the li's are clicked, I want to add an element. However, if the li has already been clicked (and the class already added), if the user clicks again, I want the class removed. So far, this is what I have:

```
(function($){ 
   $(".list li").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("hilite");
      $(this).attr("BeenClicked", "true");
   });
 })(jQuery); 

<ul class="list">
   <li> Something
   <li> Something else
</ul>
```

I need to create code that essentially checks the attribute to see if "BeenClicked" is set to true.

Comment: Err.. right. I didn't know how to, but I just figured it out. My apologies!

Comment: I agree with Joseph.  5 questions and you haven't accepted any answers yet.  Click the checkmark by the answer that you helped you the most for each question.  I will both give the checkmark and upvote a good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
(function($){ 
   $(".list li").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("hilite");
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I would consider naming that attribute 'data-beenclicked' so that it is considered valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toggleClass()` to automatically alternate the class on each click:

```
(function($){ 
   $(".list li").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("hilite");
   });
 })(jQuery); 

<ul class="list">
   <li> Something
   <li> Something else
</ul>
```

There's no need to separately store the `"BeenClicked"` attribute.  You can see if it has the class on it at any time with the `.hasClass("hilite")` method.

In addition, if you were going to store data on it, then the jQuery way would be with the `.data()` method: `$(this).data("BeenClicked", true);`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out jQuery's `toggleClass()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Just call it in your click handler.